# how i require session for a function

Tags: php, function, session

i have in my sandbox many of function, some of the function are public, and other's i want them to be only for website member's.
this is an example for a function i want it to be for website members only

```
function get_page ($dbc, $pg) {

// the database connection, our query
        $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '$pg' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

        echo '<div class=entry>';
            echo '<h1>'.$page['title'].'</h1>';
            echo '<div class="content_body">'.$page['body'].'</div>';   
        echo '</div>';
}
```

is there any way to do that?

Comment: What kind of "session"? We need specifics.

Comment: member's of the website,

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you provide for information?

Comment: You mean this >>> http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php ???

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){ die(); }` ***"how i require session for a function"***

Comment: You (also) need to know that you need to have `session_start();` inside all your documents (and at the top) in order for sessions to work. Do read up on the link I've given you above.

Comment: work perfectly fredii

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer then to close the question. Click the white checkmark till it turns green, that's how it's done here ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"how i require session for a function"***

Use the following, as an example:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){ die(); }
```

and to include [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start) inside all of the files used, and at the `*` top.
*(`*` Depending on the condition).*

For more information on sessions, visit the following:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

**Footnotes:**

Should you be faced with an `headers already sent...` error message later on, you can make use of [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) placed above `session_start()`.

For example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
// code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear. 
You can use something like:

```
// Private function for members
function privateFunction($isMember=false){

    if($isMember){
      // DO your things
    }
    else{
      callError();
    }
}
```

Or make use of PHP Session variables directly into your function ?

Comment: Judging from the OP, i really dount this answer will result in anything usable by him. You might want to try harder, provide more documentation/code. TBH, atm answering is not possible with given information.

Comment: I tried :) maybe he isn't english and have some trouble for asking question. My goal is to help nothing more nothing less.